# Using pandas to save to a csv file with date time appended to the filename

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I was running the code but am getting this error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'filename 09-30-2021 16:45:17 PM.csv'
```

Is there anyway to work around this?

```
currentDateTime = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
df.to_csv(f"filename {currentDateTime}.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? Please look into restricted characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works on Linux, but it doesn't work on Windows because of the restricted characters: `< > : " / \ | ? *`

Please replace `:` with something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. Because, you cannot have colons (:) in filenames.

```
currentDateTime = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S %p")
df.to_csv(f"filename {currentDateTime}.csv", index = False)
```